# Is multiplication always repeated addition?

Tags: field-theory, definition, universal-property

I understand that a field is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Classic_definition) a set and two operations and some properties for those operations.

As a consequence of those properties is it always the case that the operation conventionally called "multiplication" can be implemented as a repeated application of the operation called "addition", or is that a special property restricted only to some sets (e.g., $\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: This is in fact only rarely the case, even in the most common examples. Take for instance multiplication by $\frac12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, multiplication **by an integer*** is always repeated addition due to the distributivity of multiplication over addition:

$$a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$$

*I define an integer as repeated addition of the multiplicative identity ($1$) to the additive identity ($0$).

Then it's easy to see that

$$a \cdot 0 = 0$$

$$a \cdot (1 + 0) = (a \cdot 1) + (a \cdot 0)  = a$$
$$a \cdot (1 + 1 + 0) = (a \cdot 1)  +  (a \cdot 1) + (a \cdot 0) = a + a$$

Etc...

However a field may contain many elements that aren't integers by this definition, for example in the rationals $\frac{1}{2}$ can not be written as $0 + 1 + 1 + \cdots$. As long as at least one side of the multiplication (thanks to commutativity) is an integer, you can write it as repeated multiplication.

Comment: So distributivity and the existence of a multiplicative and additive identity are the crucial properties?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Correct. Be careful though, what can be considered an "integer" inside a field can be counter-intuitive.

Comment: (I'd be really convinced if I could see this illustrated graphically with $\mathbb{C}$.)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true in general, not even in the finite field case.

The problem is that the word "repeated" makes explicit reference to counting, which may not map in any obvious way to the field that we're talking about.

So for example in GF(4) we have four elements, $0, 1, x, y$ such that for all elements $A$ we have $A + A = 0$, but we have a nontrivial multiplication structure $xy = yx = 1.$There is no way to view this as a repeated addition of either $x$ or $y$ to itself, as the condition $x + x = y + y = 0$ means that repeated additions of $x$ to itself or $y$ to itself just live in the sets $\{0, x\}$ and $\{0, y\}$ respectively, never hitting the $1$ element.

Comment: Can the additional properties of a field that make multiplication always repeated addition be easily stated?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, that is if every field element is an "integer" per the definition in my answer. That is, every field element must be able to be written as $0 + 1 + 1 + \ldots$.

Comment: @orlp: So if every element of the set can be expressed as repeated addition of the multiplicative identity to the additive identity, but otherwise not?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes. And this is the case if and only if the number of elements in the field is a prime.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Or infinite? (It's not clear to me why.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No, this is never true for an infinite field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius That is not a field. It is not even a ring in fact, only a semiring.

Comment: It might be interesting to broaden to commutative rings, though?

Comment: @CRDrost Sure, in that case this holds precisely when the ring equals its prime subring which is precisely when it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ah, new to this. How about $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius How are you planning on interpreting multiplying by $i$ as a repeated addition of any kind? Repeated additions of $x$ do not rotate in the complex plane; $x$ and $x+x$ and $x+x+x$ all have the same argument. But multiplication by $i$ does: $ix$ has been rotated by $\pi/2.$ So even if we give a very generous definition of what we're talking about for the rationals, the complex numbers get hairy real fast.

Comment: @CRDrost: Or put another [way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372643/12400), _i_ (among other elements in $\mathbb{C}$) can't be written as 0 + 1 + 1 + ..., right?

Comment: Correct, $i$ and $1/2$ evade description according to @orlp's definition of integers because they cannot be written as a repeated sum of $1$ to itself. And as Tobias has said, if you want every multiplication to be interpreted as a repeated addition then you have to restrict yourself to modular arithmetic. Even $\mathbb Z$ doesn't quite work as $-1$ is not an integer according to the definition given, though possibly that definition (and what you're looking for) can be broadened to include it.

Comment: @CRDrost: I think I see now (at least formally). This leads to what is perhaps a new question, prompted by the fact that for _some_ fields this intimate relationship between multiplication and addition exists: is there in general no such relationship (even if it is pretty abstract)? My guess is, judging from $\mathbb{C}$, where addition and multiplication "go on totally different directions", there isn't.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius GF(4) is a really good counterexample to keep in mind, which is why I answered with it, but I'm not convinced you're asking the right question. For example there's a rich bit of theory concerned with $\mathbb C$ as a "field extension" of $\mathbb R$ which extends $\mathbb Q$ which extends $\mathbb Z$; you may wish to think long and hard about the $p$-adic number systems as they are a different extension of $\mathbb Q$ which have the same "intimate relationship" as $\mathbb R$ does.